# How can I achieve a greater sense of depth when the camera is inside an object in Three.js?

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I'm having an issue with Three.js regarding the camera.

I want the user to be able to explore the inside of an object, but increasing the scale of the object with the camera in the center does not appear to create the sense of depth that might be expected. Imaging standing in a 5m sq room and then the dimensions expanding to 50m sq. I would expect the details of the interior walls to get smaller as they got further away.

I have messed around with the near / far / fov setting, but cannot get the desired effect. Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing here? Thanks

Scale set to 1 at the center of object

[image: Scale set to 1 at the center of object]

[image: Scale set to 10 at the center of object]

Scale set to 10 at the center of object

Comment: i think FOV would have some effect on depth perception at least, but another option would be to include some depth of field in post-processing: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=dof#webgl_postprocessing_dof

Comment: It's hard to get a feeling of depth when your camera rotates from a fixed position, regardless of the scale of the world around it. However, you could move the camera slightly up/down and left/right to create a parallax effect. The subtle camera movement will give the impression of depth because closer objects will move faster than further ones. As an example, here's a simple demo of the parallax effect: https://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/ (just don't use that library because it's not Three.js compatible)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Don McCurdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1314762/don-mccurdy)'s point, if you have a fixed FOV and a proportionally (x,y,z) scaled up object, you don't get a sense of depth.
Illustrating in this image [FOV vs depth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr2t1.png)

I imagine you could feel a sense depth from a 5m2 to 50m2 room because your wall doesn't grow taller when they gets further away from your view point. Which isn't the exact case judging from your screenshot.

You can also try adding some constant objects in view so users get a sense of relative scale. Or move the camera/object position so user isn't at the centre.